# How can i split this string format to array for in javascript?

Tags: javascript, split

Dear all,
Currently am trying to split this string format: `x:10/08/2018,10/08/2018,10/08/2018~y:10,20,12` to array format like this:

```
    [
        { x:10/08/2018, y: 10 },
        { x:10/08/2018, y: 20 },
        { x:10/08/2018, y: 12 }
    ]
```

Who have experience with this split by using javascript could you please tell me now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Are they always `x` and `y` or can they be different symbols?

Comment: You have 5 questions and a lot of solutions! But you are with nothing satisfied! **VERY DISRESPECTFUL**!!! And you are the member on SO for 3 years. Incredible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the string using `split()` method and `~` as a separator

Next , split the first part using `,` as a separator.

Next , split the second part using `,` as a separator.

Store each `x` and its corresponding `y` inside an object , then push that object into an empty array.

Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert to JSON string format.

```js
var str = "x:10/08/2018,10/08/2018,10/08/2018~y:10,20,12";

var x = str.split("~")[0].split(":")[1].split(","); //get the value of "x"
var y = str.split("~")[1].split(":")[1].split(","); //get the value of "y";

var resultArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  resultArray.push({
    x : x[i],
    y : y[i]
  });
}

var finalResult = JSON.stringify(resultArray);

document.write(finalResult);
```

Further info can be found here:

`split()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

`JSON.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Eyad Mohammed, Thanks for your quick respond :) anyway if i have string like this: dp=x:10/08/2018,10/08/2018,10/08/2018~y:10,20,12;wd=x:10/08/2018,10/08/2018,10/08/2018~y:10,20,12 then i want to split it to    data: [{
           
            dp: [
                { x:10/08/2018, y: 10 },
    { x:10/08/2018, y: 20 },
    { x:10/08/2018, y: 12 }
            ]
        },
        {
            wd: [
                { x:10/08/2018, y: 10 },
    { x:10/08/2018, y: 20 },
    { x:10/08/2018, y: 12 }
            ]
        }]

Comment: @chhenghong I think your problem is this seems like a dynamic format. This response is generic enough for you to start working on your own

Comment: Tree Ngugen, Yes of course it is dynamic format, first i need to count length of first array after split and then loop it to split to another array. but am stack on it now. can you help me?